# php myadmin sql 1064 error on the trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

I have tried to upload the following sql command to the php myadmin. But, I have took some interesting error. I have tried to solve it but even if I think carefully, I could not find the why the error arises.

Error :

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON car_model
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @car_name VARCHAR(255)' at line 2
```

SQL :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Update 
ON car_model
FOR INSERT
AS
        DECLARE @car_name VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE @manufacturer_year VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE @car_type  VARCHAR(255);

        SELECT @car_name = i.car_name FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @manufacturer_year = i.manufacturer_year FROM inserted i;
        SELECT @car_type  = i.car_type FROM inserted i;

        INSERT INTO features 
                (car_name, manufacturer_year, car_type)
        VALUES (@car_name, @manufacturer_year, @car_type);
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `SQL Server Trigger` syntax. Here's for `MySQL`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Update 
AFTER INSERT ON car_model
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO features (car_name, manufacturer_year, car_type)
        VALUES (NEW.car_name, NEW.manufacturer_year, NEW.car_type);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [MySQL CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: can you fully write whole code with correction ? I have does what you write but still same error.

Comment: that's the whole code, you don't need to declare any variables. what is the full error message generated?

Comment: it says you have no permission to do this job. What is it, how can I solve it in php myadmin ?

Comment: so the syntax is now correct. the problem that arises now is because maybe the username that you have used to login the server hasn't enough privilege to create a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

trigger should be like that

```
   TRIGGER TRG_Update BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
```

you can see [How to Create Triggers in MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/)